# Maxima and Minima of a Funny Looking Graph

Tags: summation, curves, products, maxima-minima

I was messing around with the function
$$f_k(x)=\frac{1}{k+1}\prod_{n=1}^{k} (x-n)^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$$
because it has a [funny looking graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p3itpgfoxz). It was easy to determine that the zeroes are at
$$x=1, 2, 3, ..., k$$
But I also wanted to find the maxima and minima. After working at it for a while, I determined that
$$f_k'(x)=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{m=1}^{k}\bigg( \frac{1}{(x-m)(2m-1)}\prod_{n=1}^{k} (x-n)^{\frac{1}{2n-1}} \bigg)$$
Now I'm stuck. How the heck do I find the zeroes of this?

Just one more thing...

I also want to find a closed-form formula for the $y$-intercept in terms of $k$. This means that I would have to find a closed-form for
$$f_k(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}\prod_{n=1}^{k} n^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$$
I also have no clue how to do this. Maybe it's really easy? I don't know that much about how to evaluate products like that.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Consider temporarily the functions
$$
g_{k}(x) = [ f_{k} (x) ]^{k}
$$
These functions are polynomials, hence so are
$$
g'_{k}(x) = k  [ f_{k} (x) ]^{k-1} \; f'_{k}(x).
$$
In general, their zeros cannot be found "in radicals", because of Abel's Theorem.  That the zeros were easy to find for the $f_{k}$'s was pure luck: a convenient form of the function.